# How to interpolate values in a whole database with approx function?

Tags: r, database, interpolation

I have recorded values from different treatments at different moments. I had done a linear interpolation with these points using the approx () function. As a result I got the predicted values. I have done this procedure only for one repetition belonging to one treatment. Now I want to do it for the whole database. The criterion that I decided to use was to create a new column (see below "polyname") which include treatment+block, and then adjust approx () function with polyname as a criteria for splitting the database but I could not find how to perform this (see below the output error). Any help will be really appreciated.

Here is the script and the link with the database.

```
http://www.filedropper.com/dataexample

names(dataexample)

#To summary the categorical variables
str(dataexample)

# Transform
dataexample$x<-as.numeric(as.character(dataexample$x))
str(dataexample)


# Create a new column (polyname) combining treatment and block, separated     by ","
dataexample$polyname <- paste(dataexample$treat, dataexample$block,     sep=",")


#Split the database and run approx function with the new column polyname
model1<-lapply (split(dataexample, dataexample$polyname), approx(x, y,     method="linear", xout=7:148, yleft=0, yright=0, rule = 1, f = 0, ties =     mean))
model1

Output Error:

> #Split the database and run approx function
> model1<-lapply (split(dataexample, dataexample$polyname), approx(x, y,     method="linear", xout=7:148, yleft=0, yright=0, rule = 1, f = 0, ties =     mean))

Error in xy.coords(x, y) : object 'y' not found

> model1
Error: object 'model1' not found
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards.
Matías.

Comment: You're not using `lapply` correctly.  It should be `lapply(split(...), function(d) approx(d$x, d$y, ...))`.  See `?lapply`.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Regards. Matías.